# WkHtmlToXSharp MultiplexingConverter in client application process stays alive

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

When I use the MultiplexingConverter in a regular WinForms app, everything works fine, except when I leave the program the process stays alive. All the calls are made from the same thread, using the following code.

```
using (var pdfConverter = new MultiplexingConverter())
{
    pdfConverter.ObjectSettings.Web.EnablePlugins = false;
    pdfConverter.ObjectSettings.Web.EnableJavascript = false;
    string html = Path.GetFullPath(_arquivo);
    Uri htmlUri = new Uri(html);
    pdfConverter.ObjectSettings.Page = htmlUri.AbsoluteUri;
    pdfConverter.ObjectSettings.Load.Proxy = "none";

    var tmp = pdfConverter.Convert();

    var number = 0;
    lock (this) number = count++;
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"tmp" + (number) + ".pdf", tmp);
}
```

Has anyone seen this behavior? I know the Multiplexer has a worker thread which syncs calls from various threads, and was wondering if there is a way to signal it to stop.